# Modifying a value on a logarithmic curve

Tags: c++, algorithm, logarithm

I have one value that is a floating point percentage from 0-100, `x`, and another value that is a floating point from 0-1, `y`. As `y` gets closer to zero, it should reduce the value of `x` on a logarithmic curve.

So for example, say `x = 28.0f` and `y = 0.8f`. Since `0.8f` isn't that far from `1.0f` it should only reduce the value of `x` by a small amount, say bringing it down to `x = 25.0f` or something like that. As `y` gets closer to zero it should more and more drastically reduce the value of `x`. The only way I can think of doing this is with a logarithmic curve. I know what I want it to do, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to implement this in C++. What would this algorithm look like in C++?

Comment: It seems like you're trying to do some kind of curve fitting, but I can't tell what is going on beyond that.  Is y a function of x?  What is this "another value" that "gets closer to zero"?

Comment: Are you looking for a Newton Iteration (http://help.matheass.eu/de/NewtonIteration.html) or similar?

Comment: `y` is the "another value" I'll reword that a bit to make it more clear.

Comment: How does what you want differ from the result of simply multiplying the two numbers?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan: Simply multiplying them would be too linear of a change. I want it to start out slowly and then get more and more steep as `y` gets closer to zero. I chose a logarithmic curve because it looks like it would work better for what I want compared to an exponential one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want this:

```
new_x = x * ln((e - 1) * y + 1)
```

I'm assuming you have the natural log function `ln` and the constant `e`.  The number multiplied by `x` is a logarithmic function of `y` which is 0 when y = 0 and 1 when y = 1.

Here's the logic behind that function (this is basically a math problem, not a programming problem).  You want something that looks like the `ln` function, rising steeply at first and then leveling off.  But you want it to start at (0, 0) and then pass through (1, 1), and `ln` starts at (1, 0) and passes through (e, 1).  That suggests that before you do the `ln`, you do a simple linear shift that takes 0 to 1 and 1 to e: `((e - 1) * y + 1`.

Comment: That looks promising, and nothing like what I was trying to do, haha. I'll give this a shot in a bit and let you know.

Comment: Oh yeah, this is exactly what I'm looking for. Exactly the kind of curve I was envisioning, thank you so much. If it's not too much of a hassle, could you possibly explain how you derived this algorithm? It would help a lot in the future to know why this works.

Comment: OK, I added a little explanation, hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

We can try with the following assumption: we need a function f(y) so that f(0)=0 and f(1)=1 which follows some logarithmic curve, may be something like f(y)=A*log(B+C*y), with A, B and C constants to be determined.

f(0)=0, so B=1

f(1)=1, so A=1/log(1+C)

So now, just need to find a C value so that f(0.8) is roughly equal to 25/28. A few experiment shows that C=4 is rather close. You can find closer if you want.

So one possibility would be: f(y) = log(1.0 + 4.0*y) / log(5.0)

Comment: I'm curious, where does the log(5.0) come from?

Comment: A=1/log(1+C), C=4 so A=1/log(5), so that f(1)=1